# Firebase real time database datetime rules for calendar

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm currently in the dark because I want to create security rules to check if date on the request match the current date. I want to extrapolate it from path eg. **/calendar/2023/12/7/uid.** But currently I'm stuck how can I check and compare the year, month and a day. Is there a way to make it without passing the date directly via json body?

```
    "calendar": {
      "$year": {
        "$month": {
          "$day": {
            "$uid": {
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
            }  
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
    "calendar": {
      "$nowValue": {
        
            "$uid": {
              ".write": "auth.uid == $uid && $nowValue == now"
            }
         
      }
    }
```

i will suggest you to change the approach to check date from the year , month and day to simply use now which is just in  milliseconds which is equal to milliseconds since the epoch which is defined as the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970 here it does not counting leap seconds.
you can read more about the now [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#now)

the above uses Firebase realtime database's security rules syntax to check if the authenticated user's UID matches the $uid value in the path. Additionally, we are comparing the $nowValue value in the path with the current nowValue using the now variable provided by Firebase.

i am amusing you want compare with the current date and time but even if you are not you can use the current value and pass it to some other code block to returns accordingly logic.

let me know it it works out or not.
and
thanks to @frank van Puffelen to pointing out the mistake

Comment: From the documentation on the [`now` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#now) in security rules, it seems that its value is in milliseconds since the epoch - so it won't have properties like `year` and `month`.

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for pointing it out pleas check if it is correct now !

Comment: Thanks for the response but current path will change aswell with keys that are not applicable (same date can have multiple entries) I've read more and found that other storage gives more freedom on this topic but I'm just going to secure it more in app

Comment: i will say it will be best because if it would firestore instated of Realtime database you will have easy and fixable approach while writing security rules. :)